Find $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and a particular subspace

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{H}_1&= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x_1 +kx_3 +2x_4 = 0\}\\
\mathbb{H}_2 &= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x_1 -2x_2 -x_3 + x_4 = 0\}\\
\mathbb{S} &= \operatorname{span}\{(1,2,-1,0),(1,1,-2,1)\}\end{align*}$$
Find $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and a subspace $\mathbb{T}$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $\mathbb{H}_1^{\perp} \oplus \mathbb{T} = \mathbb{H_2}$ and $\mathbb{S} \cap \mathbb{T} \ne \{0\}$.

I found basis $\mathbb{H}_1$ as $\operatorname{span}\{(-2,0,0,1),(-k,0,1,0),(0,1,0,0)\}$.
And basis $\mathbb{H}_2$ as $\operatorname{span}\{(2,1,0,0),(1,0,1,0),(-1,0,0,1)\}$,
$$\mathbb{H}_1^{ \perp}= \operatorname{span}\{(1,0,k,2)\}$$
But I can't manage to figure out $\mathbb{T}$ or $k$.

Please be consistent in your notation and add mathjax
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

A hint for $k$: Since you want $\mathbb{H}_1^\perp$ to lie in $\mathbb{H}_2$ you should postulate that the equation $x_1 - 2x_2 - x_3 + x_4 = 0$ is satisfied for $(1,0,k,2)$.

Hint for $\mathbb{T}$, $\dim\mathbb{T}=\dim\mathbb{H}_2-\dim\mathbb{H}_1^\perp=3-1=2$, so $\mathbb{T}=span{\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}}$ for some vector a and b.

With clemens idea and other guy idea i know T is dim 2 and i know k is 3, how do I find T though?

Let $\beta_1$ be basis of $\mathbb{H}_1^\perp$ and $\beta$ be basis of $\mathbb{T}$, and let $\beta_2$ be basis for $\mathbb{H}_2$, want to find $\beta$, such that $span{\beta_1\cup\beta}=span{\beta_2}$, and $\beta$ and $\beta_1$ are disjoint.

From the hint in the comment section, we get $k=3$ easily.
Now find $\mathbb{T}$:
Since
$$e(1,2,-1,0)^T+d(1,1,-2,1)^T=a(2,1,0,0)^T+b(1,0,1,0)^T+c(-1,0,0,1)^T\\\implies a=3,b=-3,d=e=1$$ if $c=1$. The result will be used in the following.
Then consider $\mathbb{T}=span\{(2,3,-3,1)^T,(2,1,0,0)^T\}$.
Note: $(2,3,-3,1)^T=3(2,1,0,0)^T-3(1,0,1,0)^T+1(-1,0,0,1)^T$ or $=(1,2,-1,0)^T+(1,1,-2,1)^T$
Verify the subspace $\mathbb{T}$:
Let $\beta=\{(2,3,-3,1)^T,(2,1,0,0)^T\},\beta_1=\{(1,0,3,2)^T\},\\\beta_2=\{(2,1,0,0)^T,(1,0,1,0)^T,(-1,0,0,1)^T\}$.
It is obvious that $\beta\cup\beta_1$ is linearly independent and disjoint.
For any $\mathbf{x}\in span\{\beta_1\cup\beta\}$,$$\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}&=a_1(2,3,-3,1)^T+a_2(2,1,0,0)^T+a_3(1,0,3,2)^T\\
&=a_1(3(2,1,0,0)^T-3(1,0,1,0)^T+(-1,0,0,1)^T)+a_2(2,1,0,0)^T+a_3(3(1,0,1,0)^T+2(-1,0,0,1)^T)
\end{align*}$$
It implies $\mathbf{x}\in span\{\beta_2\}\implies\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{H}_2$.
Since $\mathbb{H}_1^\perp\oplus\mathbb{T}=span\{\beta\cup\beta_1\}$, so for any $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{H}_1^\perp\oplus\mathbb{T}$, it is also in $\mathbb{H}_2$, it implies $\mathbb{H}_1^\perp\oplus\mathbb{T}\subseteq\mathbb{H}_2$. The another direction shoud be similar.
Moreover, $(2,3,-3,1)^T\in\mathbb{T}$ and it is also in $\mathbb{S}$, so the condition about $\mathbb{S}$ and $\mathbb{T}$ is satsified.
Note: The notation used correspond to those I use in the comment section.
Please inform me if there are any errors.
